# Java Spring Queries

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, h2

i want to make a query buy i don't have acess to the h2 database schema so i dont know how are the join attributes named.
I basically want to query the avaiable rooms in a hotel in a certain date interval. For that i need to make a query like this:

```
   Select Room 
    From Room Inner Join Booking On Room.Id = Booking.RoomId Inner Join RoomType On RoomType.Id = Room.RoomTypeId
    Where NOT ((Booking.beginDate >= @initDate And Booking.beginDate <= @endtDate) or (Booking.beginDate >= @initDate And Booking.endDate <= @endDate)
or  (Booking.beginDate <= @initDate and Booking.endDate >= @endDate)) and Booking.Approved = 1 and RoomType.Id = @roomType)
```

In java spring:

```
@Query(........)
Iterable<Room> findAvaiableRooms(Date initDate, Date endDate, long roomType);

######## The Entities #######

@Entity
public class Booking {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private Date beginDate;
    private Date endDate;
    private boolean aproved;

    @ManyToOne
    private Room room;
}



 @Entity
    public class Room {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private long id;
        private String name;

        @ManyToOne
        private RoomType roomType;

        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="room", orphanRemoval = true)
        private Collection<Booking> bookings = new ArrayList<Booking>();
    }

@Entity
public class RoomType {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String type;
    private int price;
    private int numberOfRooms;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="roomType", orphanRemoval = true)
    private Collection<Room> rooms = new ArrayList<Room>();
}
```

I really don't know how the query should be made to be consistent with the db.

Comment: If you don't have access to the h2 database, how are you allowed to execute a query?

Comment: Can you execute a regular sql query "select * from <table>" and look at the metdata to see the column names?

Comment: @Stefan i have access to the database , i just don't know how to see the database schema

Comment: Download something like [DBeaver](http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/) and you can browse/view the tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could explicitly define the name of the join column in your annotations:

```
@Entity
public class Booking {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="room_id")
    private Room room;
}

@Entity
public class Room {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn( name="roomType_id" )
    private RoomType roomType;

}
```

Or you could also try a JPA query instead and use object-relationships, instead of tables

```
select Room r
from Room 
join r.bookings b
where 
not (   (b.beginDate >= :initDate And b.beginDate <= :endtDate)
    or  (b.beginDate >= :initDate And b.endDate   <= :endDate)
    or  (b.beginDate <= :initDate and b.endDate   >= :endDate)
)
and b.approved = true
and r.roomType = :roomType)
```

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you have all those annotations for ORM leads me to believe that you're using Hibernate.

I'd counsel you to forget about ORM until you can feel more comfortable with doing it on your own.

You are depending on Hibernate to create tables for you without fully understanding what it's going to give you.

You don't know how to write the JOIN, so you're dependent on the SQL that Hibernate generates for you.

Create the tables by hand.  Write a data access class that uses your hand-crafted SQL.  Map those results into your objects by hand.

Once you've done that you'll really understand the problem.

You will appreciate (or despise) Hibernate for what it gives you and understand how it works much better.